# C++ "group where" algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

Is there a function in the STL that will divide a sequence into contiguous subsequences where some predicate is valid?

For example the following sequence:

```
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Given a predicate `v == 1`, should return three subsequences:

```
1 1 1
1 1
1 1 1 1
```

The order of groups, and elements within those groups, should be preserved.

I can write a loop to do this in O(N) but I'm trying to learn more about the STL and avoid loops for this kind of thing. Sean Parent's great talk, [C++ Seasoning](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning), is my motivation.

Looking through `<algorithm>`, nothing jumped out at me.

Comment: Maybe the problem could also be expressed as a more generic form of tokenization? In your example the delimiters are fulfilling v!=1.

Comment: May be something possible with `std::partition_point` and `std::stable_partition` ?

Comment: It's not clear to me: *"should return three subsequences"* How should the subsequences be returned? Vector of array views? Iterators? Iterators in a container? Vector of ranges?

Comment: @Ali, I've been wondering this too. I don't know what would be most practical or idiomatic.

Comment: I'd vote for a "collection" of ranges as the most STL aligned.

Comment: @DrewNoakes while avoiding raw loops for stuff that already have a named algorithm is good practice, sometimes you hit upon something for which there doesn't exist one :-) The `find` family of algorithms only finds the first occurance and the iterator they return allow you to continue. That's where the STL left you, so you would have to write a loop around it. The alternative is a `boost::filter_iterator` that would skip all non-matching item in a lazy fashion.

Comment: @TemplateRex, thanks for the explanation and your answer. I've used C# quite a bit where there's an `IEnumerable<T>` type to represent a sequence, and it composes nicely across operators/algorithms. I'm still learning how to compose STL algorithms. It seems that having a begin/end pair makes this a little more verbose for some kinds of operations, though it does seem more flexible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such algorithm already in the Standard Library. You can write one by hand using `std::find_if` and `std::find_if_not` to find the beginning and end iterators of each occuring sequence. I think the output should be a range of `std::pair<FwdIt, FwdIt>`. The algorithm has `O(N)` complexity over its input.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<class FwdIt, class OutIt, class UnaryPred>
auto find_all_if(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, OutIt dst, UnaryPred pred)
{   
    while (first != last) {
        // start of next occurance
        auto next_b = std::find_if(first, last, pred);
        if (next_b == last) break;

        // end of next occurance
        auto next_e = std::find_if_not(next_b, last, pred);
        *dst++ = make_pair(next_b, next_e);

        first = next_e;
    }
    return dst;
}

int main()
{
    auto const v = std::vector<int> { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    using It = decltype(v.begin());
    std::vector<std::pair<It, It>> r; // "range of ranges" 

    find_all_if(begin(v), end(v), std::back_inserter(r), 
        [](auto e) { return e == 1; }
    );

    for (auto&& e : r) {
        std::cout << "[";
        std::cout << std::distance(begin(v), e.first) << ", ";
        std::cout << std::distance(begin(v), e.second) << "), ";
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9b7c528c0d8e29a) in C++14 style (use manual type definitions and function objects for the good ole C++98) that prints `[0, 3), [4, 6), [8, 12)` for your input.

Comment: I guess this is as good as it can get. Are there any algorithms from which you get multiple ranges from?

Comment: @user2672165 no, the current standard algorithms and container member functions return either nothing, a count, an iterator or a pair of iterator and bool (e.g. `map::insert`). Of course, returning an iterator into an output range of iterator pairs is simulating your requested range of ranges.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for info. Also one may reflect upon the fact that although ranges are very central to STL there is no official type(def) for a range. In your case you had to make a pair.

Comment: @user2672165 take a look at the [Standard's ranges study group](http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ranges/) where these topics are being discussed. There hase been a lot of discussion based lately.

Answer (score 1):

What is the algorithm supposed to return? A vector of ranges (pairs of iterators)? Or should it just leave a modified container whose elements that do not satisfy the criterion should be removed?

For the first case you could do it "half by hand": Use alternating [`std::find_if()` and `std::find_if_not()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) until you reach the end of the container.

For the second case apply the [remove-erase-idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Erase-Remove).

```
container.erase( std::remove_if(
        std::begin( container ), std::end( container ), 
        []( int i ){ return i != 1; } ), 
    std::end( container ) );
```

Comment: The second solution does not meet the requirements.

Comment: @user2672165 why not?

Comment: It might be too late in the evening for me, but wouldn't you only get one single range out of it?

Comment: That is correct. From the question it was not clear to me, what exactly should be the result of the computation. This is one simpler alternative.